# How to access current_user from a Rails Notification?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, security, notifications, audit-trail

I'm building an audit trail that needs to know which user is currently making the request. My audit trail is built using ActiveSupport::Notifications to receive an even that needs to be audited.

What I would like to do is use an ActiveSupport::Concern to encapsulate the logic for my audit needs, so that I can easily add auditing to any model in my system.

In general this is easy to do. I even [blogged about it a while back](http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/06/09/using-activesupportnotifications-and-activesupportconcern-to-create-an-audit-trail/). However, I'm having a hard time figuring out how to get the current user that making the request to the web server, so that I can log who is making what changes in my audit trail.

I know there are a ton of questions about "how do I get current_user in my model" but I'm not asking about doing it in a model, so I'm hoping there is a better set of answers. Since my audit code is infrastructure related, I am hoping that there is some way I can tap into the current request that is being processed, or something else that would definitively tell me who is currently logged in / making the request.

I've read a lot of "answers" that say to use thread storage and put the current_user in there. I don't like this answer for many of the reasons that others don't - there is no guarantee that thread storage is safe. it could bleed across multiple requests if the server uses the same thread to process multiple requests, etc.

so... given that I am not trying to access current_user from my model, but rather from either an ActiveSupport::Concern or ActiveSupport::Notifications event subscription, are there any good options for me to know who the current user is?

**Update**

I'm using devise for authentication, which uses Warden on the back end. devise retrieves the current_user by calling `request.env['warden'].authenticate(:scope => :user)` (assuming i use a "User" model for authentication).

Is there a way for me to access the current `request` object from within my concern or notification subscription? Back in my .NET days, I would have been able to call `HttpContext.Current.Request` and all would be good. What's the equivalent in Rails?

Comment: thanks for the link fix. :) was just about to do that and saw you had taken care of it!

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? If you did, please do write about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Rails' `ActionController::Instrumentation` has explicit support for this, using `append_info_to_payload`.

Add a method to your `ApplicationController`:

```
def append_info_to_payload(payload)
  super
  payload[:current_user_id] = current_user.try(&:id)
end
```

now, when your observer is called back, the information will be in the `event.payload`:

```
ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe /process_action.action_controller/ do |*args|
  event = ActiveSupport::Notifications::Event.new(*args)
  current_user_id = event.payload[:current_user_id]
  # do something interesting with current_user_id here
end
```

Comment: Thanks for this info, is this still the best way?

Comment: It still seems active  https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Instrumentation.html#method-i-append_info_to_payload

I'm unclear though whether only notifications from action_controller would have this.  I'm using rack-attack and trying to access current_user for logging

Answer (score -1):

You already have the answer, what you're doing is the same as when people are accessing the request in models.  The current_user is just a method defined on your ApplicationController.  When you're not in a controller or other class that inherits from it, you can't access that method.

HttpContext.Current.Request  << I would bet a lot that this uses thread storage.  Any other solution we find will also be thread storage at some level or another.

Either pull out what you need from the request in the controller and pass it down as parameters, or use thread storage -- but this is inherently dangerous anyway.  What if you start using delayed job to do the notifications or something?

Comment: Turns out this is possible, using rails explicit functionality, without needing thread local storage, using `append_info_to_payload`